# Как в aiogram отправлять сообщение в конкретный чат?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Как можно отправить сообщение в конкретный чат имея ID чата?

Comment: `bot.send_message(chat_id, message)`. Отправить можно только, если бот есть в этом чате и у него есть соответствующие права.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/). Намного проще в использовании

Пример:

```
await client.send_file(id_chanel, event.media, event.message)
```